# Channel capacity of sum of symmetric channels

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory, entropy

I've got a channel matrix $P$ of the form $\begin{bmatrix}
    Q  \\
    R 
  \end{bmatrix}$ where $Q,R$ are channel matrices of symmetric channels, so they now have different input alphabets but the same output alphabet.

How do you work out the capacity of this channel?

Intuitively I feel like it would be the maximum of the capacities of the individual channel matrices but I really have no idea how to start on proving it.

Thanks!

Comment: "so they now have different input alphabets but the same output alphabet"  That's not very clear for me. Could you elaborate?